# how to form an array of inputs on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to create a form which can submit the values as the below format

```
[
   {
       "_id": "59817f39808768495728ae94",
       "updatedAt": "2017-08-02T07:33:00.578Z",
       "createdAt": "2017-08-02T07:28:57.310Z",
       "farmId": "tesform",
       "farmName": "tesform",
       "gatewayId": "123",
       "gatewayName": "testform getway",
       "userId": "abc@kisanraja.com",
       "description": "test details 1st time",           
       "nodes": [
           {
               "permanentAddress": "",
               "description": "with temparature",
               "name": "Node 1",
               "_id": "5981802c808768495728ae9b",
               "sensors": [
                   {
                       "units": "C",
                       "max": 60,
                       "min": -6,
                       "name": "temparature",
                       "_id": "5981802c808768495728ae9c"
                   }
               ],
               "shortAddress": 0
           },
           {
               "permanentAddress": "",
               "description": "with soil moisture and voltage",
               "name": "Node 2",
               "_id": "5981802c808768495728ae98",
               "sensors": [
                   {
                       "units": "C",
                       "max": 60,
                       "min": -6,
                       "name": "moisture",
                       "_id": "5981802c808768495728ae9a"
                   },
                   {
                       "units": "C",
                       "max": 60,
                       "min": -6,
                       "name": "voltage",
                       "_id": "5981802c808768495728ae99"
                   }
               ],
               "shortAddress": 0
           }
       ]
   }
]
```

I want to create the nodes and sensors dynamically using jquery. Each farm should have more than one node, and each node may have more than one sensor.

Comment: I don't really get your question

Comment: You need to extend this question drastically. If you want someone to help you - there needs to be an explicit question. Are you having trouble submitting the form? Creating the form? Receiving data on your back-end? It is really unclear and should be extended asap.

Comment: provide the form html too

Comment: Please show an example of the form and any attempts you've made so far. Better still provide a [mcve].

Comment: I thing you should read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Before Asking Question. it will help you in asking question on the site

Answer (score 0):

You can add different class names to different level inputs, then each them, when came cross nodes, add nodes to object, when came cross to sensors, then add sensors to array as an attributes of node object named sensors when submit the form:

```
 $("#form").submit(function() {
  //deal with them;
```

});